# If I've created a multichain node using params anyone can connect can i change it now?

Tags: blockchain

If I've  created a multichain node using params anyone can connect can i change it now ? i want only few more nodes to be able to connect to my running multichain-node. I want to block malicious notes to be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

MultiChain 2.0 beta 2, scheduled for release next week, will allow this. You'll need to first upgrade your blockchain to the latest protocol, and then you can upgrade the anyone-can-connect parameter.